# XML Deserialization Issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, xml-serialization

I have the following xml that's sent to me from a web service.  I'm using .NET to deserialize it, but I'm getting an exception saying that its formatted wrong. `There is an error in XML document (2, 2)`  Now, if I understand that correctly, it's not liking that it's finding the first `<error>` node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xml">
  <error>error text</error>
  <message>message text</message>
</messages>
```

my code looks like this, data being the `String` version of the XML above:

```
Dim resp As cResponseMessage
Dim sr As New StringReader(data)
Dim xs As New XmlReaderSettings()

Dim xd As New XmlSerializer(GetType(cResponseMessage))
resp = xd.Deserialize(XmlTextReader.Create(sr, xs))
```

and `cResponseMessage` is simply a class with an `XMLRoot` attribute and 2 properties with `XMLElement` attributes.  Nothing fancy here, but it doesn't want to work.

Any help would be great.

Comment: You should also post the definition of the cResponseMessage class.  That's probably where the disconnect is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class works for me:

```
<XmlRoot(Namespace:="http://www.w3.org/1999/xml", ElementName:="messages")> _
Public Class cResponseMessage

    <XmlElement> _
    Public Property [error] As String
        Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
    End Property

    <XmlElement> _
    Public Property message As String
        Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in XML document (2, 2) looks to me like it would be the m in <messages>.

Perhaps you don't have your XmlRoot set up correctly in cResponseMessage?